# Why is our FastCGI/IIS MaxInstances setting is not being honored? Getting only two process instances when we want 16

Tags: python, fastcgi

Python.exe as target app.  Running FastCGI under IIS, single worker process.

We have configured for 16 maxInstances( = number of cores as the app is CPU-bound) which was working great and suddenly it is only spinning up two processes.  Nothing has (or should have) changed.

The interwebs haven't helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: _suddenly it is only spinning up two processes_ What changed in between the time it was working and now?  Did you make any configuration changes?  Rebuild/redeploy the application?  Upgrade the hardware?  Upgrade a dependent package?  Are other services running on the same pc?

Comment: We've ruled out anything like that as best as we could.  Honestly, this post is a bit of shot in the dark that someone might know of something fairly obscure.

Comment: it turns out that this was a client-side issue.  Verified by good old wireshark and/or your favorite resource monitoring tool, our client was changed to use a .NET HttpClient singleton which defaults to only two(2) connections per endpoint/domain-name.  I leave this here as a warning to be so sure you know _where_ the source of the problem actually is, and don't be too overconfident in your end of things when the other end starts behaving differently.